# Replicating sql server report database to a different machine then modify data source automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a SQL server reporting service production environment. I need to duplicate this environment on a totally different machine including the source data, let's call it Dev environment. I have backed up and restored both the source database (sourceDataDB) and the report databases (ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB) to this new machine. Re-configured the new reporting service to point to the new report database. Everything works except when I run a report, the report pull out data from the original source database instance instead of the newly created instance. Of course, I can manually modify the data source information from the Report Manager on the new report server. The challenge is every time the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB got refreshed from the production database, the modified data source got replaced with the one from production environment.

I wonder if there is a way to automate the process of modifying data source information after each database refresh, either from the database end or from the report manager. I only have one data source that is shared with all the reports. This is a SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks in advance.